# Firebase - index on .value not giving sorted results

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure like so:

```
{
   "inbox_events": {
      "from_users": {
         "uid1": {
            "uid2": 1501337181,
            "uid3": 1501337183,
            "uid4": 1501337179
         },
         "uid2" : {
            "uid6": 1501337284,
            "uid1": 1501337295
         }
      }
   }
}
```

with the following rules:

```
{
   "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "inbox_events": {
         "from_users": {
            "$userId": {
               ".indexOn": ".value"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Problem**: I don't understand why the indexing on value does not work. In the firebase console, entries for each `$userId` are still ordered in alphabetical order and if I do a `queryOrderedByValue`, I am not getting a sorted result.

Have I misread the Firebase doc?

Thanks in advance !

---

**EDIT:**

Specifically, I am trying to query the data like so:

```
let queryRef = Database.database().reference().child("inbox_events").child("from_users").child("uid1").queryOrderedByValue()
queryRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print("key: \(snapshot.key), value: \(snapshot.value)")
})
```

in order to get the sorted list, by descending value, of `uid`s at the `uid1` node.

Comment: Post some code. Also, specify which platform do you use (Android, iOS, Web, Admin SDK, REST API, whatever)

Comment: @DimaRostopira: added what I intend to do, platform is iOS as rightfully edited by Frank Van P.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to do; you want to query by value but the uid's are the keys. Also, Firebase doesn't offer a descending option for ordering, although there are ways to do it. Finally, .index doesn't directly impact how items are sorted - it's a performance enhancement for queries. Can you clarify what the expected output would be?

Comment: @Jay: sure, sorry about that. Expected output would be: ["uid3", "uid2", "uid4"] because 1501337183 > 1501337181 > 1501337179.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so easy to overlook.

The result is combined into a single snapshot, and when printed, the data is converted to a dictionary which looses it's order.

To maintain the correct order, iterate over the returned snapshot.

Here's your code with the converted snapshot, and then how to iterate over the snapshot to maintain order

```
let queryRef = self.ref.child("inbox_events").child("from_users").child("uid1").queryOrderedByValue()
queryRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //converts to dict
    print("key: \(snapshot.key), value: \(snapshot.value)")

    //keeps the order
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        print("key: \(snap.key), value: \(snap.value)")
    }
})
```